# "Create New AVD" window looks different

Tags: android-virtual-device, eclipse-juno

[image: The GUI that I see when I add a new AVD]

[image: The GUI on developer.android.com]

I am trying to create an Android virtual device for my application. However, options to for creating a new AVD is limited for me. I have Eclipse Juno and Android 4.0 installed. How can I get the "Create new Android Virtual Device (AVD)" window as seen on the second picture.